# How to make an Smooth Movement in C++, SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a problem doing an smooth movement in c++ w/ sfml.
Someone can make an algorithm to smooth move a shape / sprite by 15 px (the sprite / shape is 15 px) by pressing a button? Thanks.

Comment: What have your attempts at creating such an algorithm been?

Comment: I don't know how to make an SMOOTH movement, I know the "fixed" movement (identifier.move(x,y)).

Comment: There' s NO "smooth" or "fixed" movement, just use smallers values

Answer (score 1):

Because many other programmers might want to know that, here it is, but next time ask a more precise question
Here's **my** way to make a smooth movement:

Take your initial movement, lets say `25, 15` per second
Make a loop like this:

```
void GameEngine::GameLoop()
{
    sf::Clock timer;
    sf::Time tickRate;

    sf::Vector2f movement(25.0,15.0); // Your movement vector

    while(/* wahtever */){
        tickRate = timer.restart();
        yourShape.move(movement * ((float)tickRate.asMilliseconds() / 1000)); //Move your shape depending on the time elapsed between two frame

        yourWindow.clear();
        yourWindow.draw(yourShape);
        yourWindow.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Error when doing this: **movement** * (float)tickRate.asMilliseconds() **/** 1000